USING A CUSTOM IK SOLVER
I am trying to write a personal IK solver for Moveit2, I have changed the kinematics.yaml file from kdl_kinematics_plugin/KDLKinematicsPlugin to mine but when I launch the demo for panda_moveit_configuration it does not work:
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1729530735.035715522] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.move_group.cartesian_path_service_capability]: Computed Cartesian path with 1 points (followed 0.000000% of requested trajectory)
There is also another difference, in RViz using kdl_kinematics_plugin/KDLKinematicsPlugin I can manuallt move the arm into the desired position, with mine not.
Here is have the package I made, in order to better understand the moveit2 connections and API I have copied the source code of kdl_kinematics_plugin
